# Trying to build a distributed crawler with ZeroMQ

Tags: c#, php, zeromq

I just started to learn ZeroMQ and want to build a distributed webcrawler as an example while learing.

My idea is to have a "server", written in PHP, which accepts a url where the crawling should start.

Workers (C# cli) will have to crawl that url, extract links, and push them back into a stack on the server. The server keeps sending urls in the stack to workers. 
Perhaps a redis will keep track of all crawled urls, so we dont crawl sites multiple times and have the ability to extract statistics of the current process.

I would like to have the server to distribute tasks evenly, be aware of new/missing workers and redistribute urls when a worker doesnt respond.

*Why PHP for the server:* i'm just very comfortable with PHP, that is all. I dont want to make the example/testing project more complicated.

*Why C# for the minions:* because it runs on most windows machines. I can give the executable to various friends which can just execute it and help me test my project.

The crawling process and redis functionality are not part of my question.

My first approach was the PUSH/PULL pattern, which generally works for my scenario, but isnt aware of it's minions. I think i need a DEALER/ROUTER broker in the middle and have to handle the worker-awareness for myself.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504559/zeromq-push-pull-pattern-usefullness) but i'm not really sure if i understand the answer...

I'm asking for some hints how to impement the zmq stuff. Is the dealer approach correct? Is there any way to get an automatic worker-awareness? I think I need some resources/examples, or do you think that i just need to dig deeper in the zmq guide?

However, some hints towards the right direction would be great :)

Cheers

Comment: Did you look at the AsyncSvr example?

Comment: I must have skipped that, but it looks promissing. I'll take a deeper look at it later. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm building a job/task distributor that works the same as your crawler, in principal, at least. Here's a few things I've learned:

## Define All Events

Communication between server and crawlers will be based on different things happening in your system, such as dispatching work from server to crawler, or a crawler sending a heartbeat message to the server. Define the system's event types; they are the use cases:

```
DISPATCH_WORK_TO_CRAWLER_EVENT
CRAWLER_NODE_STATUS_EVENT
...
```

## Define a Message Standard

All communication between server and crawlers should be done using ZMsg's, so define a standard that organizes your frames, something like this:

```
Frame1: "Crawler v1.0"             //this is a static header
Frame2: <event type>               //ex: "CRAWLER_NODE_STATUS_EVENT"
Frame3: <content xml/json/binary>  //content that applies to this event (if any)
```

Now you can create message validators to validate ZMsgs received between peers since you have a standard convention all messages must follow.

## Server

Use a single `ROUTER` on the server for asynchrounous and bidirectional communication with the crawlers. Also, use a `PUB` socket for broadcasting heartbeat messages.

Don't block on the ROUTER socket, use a `POLLER` to loop every 5s or whatever, this allows the server to do other things periodically, like broadcast heartbeat events to the crawlers; something like this:

```
Socket rtr = .. //ZMQ.ROUTER
Socket pub = .. //ZMQ.PUB  
ZMQ.Poller poller = new ZMQ.Poller(2)
poller.register( rtr, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN)                               
poller.register( pub, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN)

  while (true) {
     ZMsg msg = null            
     poller.poll(5000)

     if( poller.pollin(0)){
        //messages from crawlers                         
        msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(rtr)
     }

     //send heartbeat messages
     ZMsg hearbeatMsg = ...
     //create message content here,
     //publish to all crawlers
     heartbeatMsg.send(pub)
  }
```

To address your question about worker awareness, a simple and effective method uses a FIFO stack along with the heartbeat messages; something like this:

- server maintains a simple FIFO stack in memory
- server sends out heartbeats; crawlers respond with their node name; the ROUTER automatically puts the address of the node in the message as well (read up on message [enveloping](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php%3achapter3))
- push 1 object onto the stack containing the node name and node address
- when the server wants to dispatch work to a crawler, just pop the next object from the stack, create the message and address is properly (using the node address), and off it goes to that worker
- dispatch more work to other crawlers the same way; when a crawler responds back to the server, just push another object with node name/address back on the stack; the other workers won't be available until they respond, so we don't bother them.

This is a simple but effective method of distributing work based on worker availability instead of blindly sending out work. Check [lbbroker.php](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/PHP/lbbroker.php) example, the concept is the same.

## Crawler (Worker)

The worker should use a single `DEALER` socket along with a `SUB`. The `DEALER` is the main socket for async communication, and the SUB subscribes to heartbeat messages from the server. When the worker receives a heartbeat messages, it responds to the server on the DEALER socket.

```
Socket dlr = .. //ZMQ.DEALER
Socket sub = .. //ZMQ.SUB
ZMQ.Poller poller = new ZMQ.Poller(2)
poller.register( dlr, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN)                               
poller.register( sub, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN)

  while (true) {
     ZMsg msg = null            
     poller.poll(5000)

     if( poller.pollin(0)){
        //message from server                         
        msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(dlr)
     }

     if( poller.pollin(1)){
      //heartbeat message from server
       msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(sub)
       //reply back with status
       ZMsg statusMsg = ...
       statusMsg.send(dlr)
  }
```

The rest you can figure out on your own. Work through the [PHP](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/PHP) examples, build stuff, break it, build more, it's the only way you'll learn!

Have fun, hope it helps!

Comment: Very nice and encouraging answer.