# How to know if a ZeroMQ socket is ready?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have a simple `PUSH/PULL` ZeroMQ code in Python. It looks like below.

```
  def zmqtest(self):

     print('zmq')
     Process(target=start_consumer, args=('1', 9999)).start()
     Process(target=start_consumer, args=('2', 9999)).start()

     ctx = zmq.Context()
     socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
     socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:9999')
     # sleep(.5) # I have to wait here...

     for i in range(5):
        socket.send_unicode('{}'.format(i))
```

The problem is I have to wait more than **.5** second before sending message, otherwise only one consumer process can receive a message. If I wait more than .5 second, everything looks fine.

I guess it takes a while before the socket binding to settle down, and it is done asynchronously.

I wonder if there's a more reliable way to know when the socket is ready.

Comment: I believe this startup behavior is expected when pushing to multiple pull endpoints.  See also [ZeroMQ Push/Pull pattern usefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504559/zeromq-push-pull-pattern-usefulness)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Sure it takes a while.
Sure it is done async.

Let's damage first a bit the terminology.

ZeroMQ is a great framework. Each distributed-system's client, willing to use it ( except using just the `inproc://` transport class ), **first instantiates** an async data-pumping engine .. **the `Context()`** instance(s), as needed.

Each Scalable Formal Communication Pattern `{ PUSH | PULL | ... | XSUB | SUB | PAIR }` does **not** create a socket,
but
rather instantiates an **access-point**, that may later `.connect()` or `.bind()` to some counterparty ( another access-point, of a suitable type, in some `Context()` instance, be it local or not ( again, the local-`inproc://`-only infrastructures being the known exception to this rule ) ).

In this sense, an answer to a question "**When the socket is ready?**" requires an end-to-end investigation "across" the distributed-system, handling all the elements, that participate on the **socket**-alike behaviour's implementation.

---

### Testing a "local"-end access-point RTO-state:

For this, your agent may self-connect a receiving access-point ( working as a **`PULL`** archetype ), so as to "sniff", when the local-end `Context()` instance has reached an RTO-state + a `.bind()`- created O/S L3+ interface starts distributing the intended agent's-**`PUSH`**-ed messages.

---

### Testing a "remote"-agent's RTO-state:

This part can have an indirect or an explicit testing. An indirect way may use a message-embedded index. That can contain a raising number ( an ordinal ), which bears a weak information about an order. Given the `PUSH`-side message-routing strategy is Round-robin, the local-agent can be sure, that until it's local `PULL`-access-point receives all messages indicating a contiguous sequence of ordinals, there is no other "remote"-`PULL`-ing agent in an RTO-state. Once the "local" `PULL`-access-point receives "gap" in the stream of ordinals, that means ( sure, only in the case all the `PUSH`'s `.setsockopt()`-s were setup properly ) there is another -- **non-local** -- `PULL`-ing agent in an RTO-state.

---

### Is this usefull?

Maybe yes, maybe not. The point was to better understand the new challenges that any distributed-system has to somehow cope with.

The nature of multi-stage message queuing, multi-layered implementation ( local-`PUSH`-agent's-code, local `Context()`-thread(s), local-O/S, local-kernel, LAN/WAN, remote-kernel, remote-O/S, remote `Context()`-thread(s), remote-`PULL`-agent's-code to name just a few ) and multi-agent behaviour simply introduce many places, where an operation may gain latency / block / deadlock / fail in some other manner.

Yes, a walk on a wild-side.

Nevertheless, one may opt to use a much richer, explicit signalling ( besides the initially thought just a raw-data transport ) and help to solve the context-specific, signalling-RTO-aware behaviour inside the multi-agent worlds, that may better reflect the actual situations and survive also the other issues that start to appear in non-monolythic worlds of distributed-systems.

Explicit signalling is one way to cope with.

---

### Fine-tune the ZeroMQ infrastructure. Forget using defaults. Always!

Recent API versions started to add more options to fine-tune the ZeroMQ behaviour for particular use-cases. Be sure to read carefully all details available to setup **`Context()`**-instance to tweak the socket instance access-point behaviour, so that it best matches your distributed-system signalling + transport needs:

```
.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER,     0 )         # always, indeed ALWAYS
.setsockopt( ZMQ_SNDBUF,    .. )         # always, additional O/S + kernel rules apply ( read more about proper sizing )
.setsockopt( ZMQ_SNDHWM,    .. )         # always, problem-specific data-engineered sizing
.setsockopt( ZMQ_TOS,       .. )         # always, indeed ALWAYS for critical systems
.setsockopt( ZMQ_IMMEDIATE, .. )         # prevents "loosing" messages pumped into incomplete connections
```

and many more. Without these, design would remain nailed into a coffin in the real-world transaction's jungle.